# How to combine squid reverse proxy with nginx proxy for shiny-server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, squid

I have a nginx web server which acts as a proxy for my shiny-server. I now want to use a squid reverse proxy to provide access to the nginx server (and thus the shiny server) to internet clients. Currently, I can access the nginx server (and thus the shiny-server) through a web browser on my local network.

My objective is to configure the Squid & Nginx instances such that they can pass traffic between them.

nginx.conf (edited for brevity):

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    return       301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /path/to/server/directory;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
        proxy_redirect / $scheme://$http_host/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 20d;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

squid.conf (edited for brevity):

```
cache_peer shiny.domain.com parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=shinyHost login=PASS
acl shinyACL dstdomain shiny.domain.com
cache_peer_access shinyHost allow shinyACL
http_access allow shinyACL
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need squid in reverse proxying mode with nginx, thus you shouldn't use it. If you want to cache anything that upstream gives your nginx - you should do it using nginx [ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) by configuring what to cache.

Comment: Squid is in front of nginx in this case. I want my Squid server to forward requests to the nginx server (which in turn is forwarding to the shiny-server).

Comment: That was actually a typo. And no, you still don't want to.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Comment: The caching is not the feature I'm really looking for here. In my setup, I host many webservers via one IP address, which is handled by Squid. It is not an option to stop using Squid in this case as a lot of existing architecture relies on it. I do not have additional IPs. I need the nginx server as part of my authentication for the shiny-server (at this stage, I would like to change this at some point but can't right now.)

Comment: You don't need any additional IPs. Unlimited number of virtual hosts can be hosted just on one IPs. OSes/browsers that don't support SNI are long-gone obsoleted legacy now. You see to be a hostage of wrong architectural solution, but you still don't need squid anyway.

Comment: To be clear, you are saying there is a way for me to redirect traffic to my local Nginx host from my public IP, whilst leaving my Squid proxy in place

Comment: Nope, I'm saying you don't need squid at all. Hard to guess, but probably shutting down squid while changing nginx listening ports to 80 and 443 won't have any effect on your service at all.

Comment: Squid is currently used in my setup to delegate requests to a range of other virtual hosts. I'm sure you're right I could do that part with an alternative method but I'm trying to avoid to reconfigure the whole proxy at short notice.

Comment: You can `proxy_pass` whatever virtual hosts that aren't on this local machine. Furthermore, you can use `upstream` groups, in-band healthchecks, custom error pages and lots of other things your squid has no idea about and will never have (because it's primary use now is user authentication in an enterprise environment). In fact, you're denying heaven while sticking to the current hell you're in. Accept the nginx, purge squid. The more time you lose, the more services you attach to squid, the more harmful the transition will be.